# How to determine the number of homomorphisms of a group G in $Z_m$?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Is there a simple way to determine the number of homomorphisms of a group $G$ generated by a finite subset $A$ in $Z_m$?

I was studying and I came across that if $A$ generates the group $G$ the amount of homomorphism of $G$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is $m^{|A|}$. I don't understand why. What do you think: $m$ is the number of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_m$, so does $m^{|A|}$ correspond to a homomorphism of a single element?

Ps: if instead of homomorphism it was just a map, can we say that the number of maps of $G$ in $Z_m$ is $m^{|A|}$?

Comment: What is $A$ supposed to be?

Comment: A is a finite set that generates G

Comment: That claim about $m^{|A|}$ is quite false. This is an upper bound but the actual number of homomorphisms can be much smaller, all the way down to $1$ (the zero homomorphism). Anyway, take the abelianization of $G$, which reduces the problem to the case of abelian groups. If $G$ is finitely generated so is its abelianization; then work one prime at a time by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: By "amount" do you mean "number?"

Comment: That's it, Thomas

Comment: In general the number of maps from a finite set $X$ to a finite set $Y$ will have order $\vert Y \vert ^{\vert X \vert}$. This is why we use the notation $Y^X$ for all the function from $X$ to $Y$. Can you see how that applies here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G$ is the *free group* generated by $A$, then by the universal property,  the number of homomorphisms from $G$ to $\Bbb Z_m$ is $m^{\lvert A\rvert}$.

As for maps in general, not necessarily homomorphisms,  from any $G$ to $\Bbb Z_m$, we get $m^{\lvert G\rvert }$ such.